# Getting Error in Cordova Installation in Mac Terminal

Tags: android, macos, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've followed http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface.

When,I type in Mac Terminal

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

The Error is-

```
path.js:360
    throw new TypeError('Arguments to path.join must be strings');
          ^
ypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings
at path.js:360:15
at Array.filter (native)
at Object.exports.join (path.js:358:36)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/util.js:25:31)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
```

Please if any one have any Idea about the cause of error and How it can be resolved. Please Share it.

Thanks in Advance.!!

Comment: have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21242582/2567813

Comment: ya checked. still same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Finally Got the Solution. Steps to Follow-

`Install latest version of Node` [HERE](http://nodejs.org)

```
Open vim .bash_profile in terminal

Type export PATH=${PATH}: <Android SDK Tools Path>

Type source .bash_profile in Terminal
```

and finally follow [HERE](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface)